# How Can I Highlight Hashtags in my react code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I Want to Highlight Hashtags in my react code like Instagram
or any social media like
also mentions user in it

how can I do that?
whats the react module for that

> Please inform me a JSX Module, not TypeScript One

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Also, seeking recommendations for books, software libraries or other off-site resources is off-topic in StackOverflow because these kind of questions tends to lead to opinion-based answers.

Comment: Hello @kojauio could you give us an example of what you are trying to do? Please use a https://codesandbox.io/ so anyone can access to your example.